# SABRE - Create PNR for specific brand

Tags: rest, sabre

I am integrating with SABRE create PNR Rest API, now we are on live environment (doing smoke testing).

When we create a PNR, we successfully see it on SABRE system (the black screens) but the created PNR is not representing the selected flight.

For example, I select the cheapest flight when searching on our portal but on SABRE system it shows that the created one is the highest (most expensive) flight.

I am adding the fare basis code in the request body also, but this did not solve the problem.

Should we add other things in order to solve this issue?

Here is the request body for more details:

```
    {
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.4.0",
    "targetCity": "targetCity-here",
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
        "AgencyInfo": {
            "Ticketing": {
                "TicketType": "7TAW"
            }
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
            "ContactNumbers": {
                "ContactNumber": [
                    {
                        "NameNumber": "1",
                        "Phone": "0799888889",
                        "PhoneUseType": "B"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "PersonName": [
                {
                    "NameNumber": "1",
                    "GivenName": "Husni",
                    "PassengerType": "ADT",
                    "Surname": "Zakarya"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "AirBook": {
        "OriginDestinationInformation": {
            "FlightSegment": [
                {
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2024-03-14T12:55:00",
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2024-03-14T12:55:00",
                    "FlightNumber": "610",
                    "NumberInParty": "1",
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
                    "Status": "NN",
                    "DestinationLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "DXB"
                    },
                    "OriginLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "AMM"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "RJ",
                        "FlightNumber": "610"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2024-03-21T16:15:00",
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2024-03-21T16:15:00",
                    "FlightNumber": "611",
                    "NumberInParty": "1",
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
                    "Status": "NN",
                    "DestinationLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "AMM"
                    },
                    "OriginLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "DXB"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "RJ",
                        "FlightNumber": "611"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "RedisplayReservation": {
            "NumAttempts": 10,
            "WaitInterval": 300
        }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
        "EndTransaction": {
            "Source": {
                "ReceivedFrom": "11111111111111111"
            }
        }
    },
    "AirPrice": [
        {
            "PriceRequestInformation": {
                "Retain": true,
                "OptionalQualifiers": {
                    "FOP_Qualifiers": {
                        "BasicFOP": {
                            "Type": "CK"
                        }
                    },
                    "PricingQualifiers": {
                        "PassengerType": [
                            {
                                "Code": "ADT",
                                "Quantity": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "CommandPricing": [
                            {
                                "FareBasis": {
                                    "Code": "QANJOP"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
        "SpecialService": {
            "SpecialServiceInfo": {
                "AdvancePassenger": [
                    {
                        "Document": {
                            "IssueCountry": "JO",
                            "ExpirationDate": "2026-10-20",
                            "Number": "P106022222",
                            "Type": "P"
                        },
                        "PersonName": {
                            "GivenName": "Husni",
                            "Surname": "Zakarya",
                            "DateOfBirth": "1975-05-02"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I was sending the cabin class instead of booking code in "ResBookDesigCode" in the request.

Hope this can help others.